# Why does sharepoint claim not enougth disk space for backup when there is lots availalbe?

Tags: backup, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to run the following command:

```
Backup-SPFarm -Directory E:\Backups -BackupMethod full -Verbose
```

However it errors saying there isn't enough disk space... the backup will be about 1.8Gb in size, I have 27.52GB free, so why does it think I need 30Gb?

```
VERBOSE: Leaving BeginProcessing Method of Backup-SPFarm.
VERBOSE: Performing operation "Backup-SPFarm" on Target "SHAREPOINTSERV".
Backup-SPFarm : There is not enough disk space. Free additional space on your h
ard disk and then try again. Approximate amount of space needed: 30.12 GB. Amou
nt of space free on disk: 27.52 GB.
At E:\Backups\Script\BackupSharePointFarm.ps1:3 char:14
+ Backup-SPFarm <<<<  -Directory E:\Backups -BackupMethod full -Verbose
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...mdletBackupFarm:
   SPCmdletBackupFarm) [Backup-SPFarm], SPException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletBackupFa
   rm

VERBOSE: Leaving ProcessRecord Method of Backup-SPFarm.
VERBOSE: Leaving EndProcessing Method of Backup-SPFarm.
```

Comment: What makes you think it'll be 1.8GB? I believe a full farm backup will included the content databases, and such, which will also include the log files.  Have you looked at the size of the content DB log files? They grow pretty quickly.

Comment: Because I've previously been able to back up and the files are quite small - around 600MB (I was wrong 4 days backup was 1.8Gb). However I have looked at the files and the log file for sharepoint config (SharePoint_Config_log.LDF) is massive (30Gb) considering the size of the content db (only has about 30 or 40 small docs in it - do you know why this would be? I was under the impression running a full backup cleared out the log files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to the SharePoint_Config log file being too big - around 30Gb in my case!

I found [this blog article](http://blog.mpecsinc.ca/2009/08/sbs-bpa-reduce-size-of-sharepoint.html) pointing to [here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-US;2000544).

Hope it helps (I didn't test it - I changed Recovery model to Simple (After running a full backup) then srink'ed the log file and changed it back to full - I suspect next month it'll be back at 30Gb again ?!?. I hate sharepoint.

Comment: If you're not using the feature, I'd suggest just leaving the recovery model set to "Simple."  This is the easiest way to stop your .ldf file from blowing up.